# Parse out file path from dsget user -hmdir and use it in net use to map drive

Tags: batch-file

so, here is my situation, any users i have that have a homedrive configured in AD and log in via WiFi only, lose the drive, so i want to make a batch script that gets the file path from AD, then maps it.  so this command gets the path

dsquery domainroot -samid %username% | dsget user -hmdir

but it returns

hmdir
 \servername\servershares\share
dsget succseded

so i need to parse out \servername\severshare\share and assign it to a variable, then pass it to the NET USE command.  I am just getting super frustrated with string management in batch.  any help on how to parse out the file path would be much appreciated.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there aren't spaces in your `\servername\servershares\share` then it's can be solved with a FOR/F loop.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%A in (`"dsquery domainroot -samid %username% | dsget user -hmdir"`) do (
    set "share=%%A"
    goto :leaveLoop
)
:leaveLoop
echo %share%
```

Comment: if i put this into a batch file and run it, it sets the variable %share% to domainroot.  its getting close.

Comment: it doesn't return spaces, but there is new lines if you out put it to a text file.  1. hmdir 2. \\servername\sharename\share 3.dsget succseded.

Comment: @Necromporph - I change the code bit, perhaps it could work now

Comment: that doesnt seem to assign anything to the variable the tokens seem to be applying towards the command, rather then the output.  it is very frustrating, lol.  thanks for all your help.

Comment: I missed that you didn't need the second token, instead you need the complete second line

Comment: RAH!!!!!!!  thats awesome, is there any way to parse out the white space?  it is returning     \\server\servershare\share.  but it is so very close!

Comment: Where do you got a white space? And does it care? If you use the `%share%` only for the `net use` command it shouldn't make any difference

Comment: net use P:\ %share% looks like this   P:     \\Server1\Users\Username  and says the path is not valid.

Comment: ugh it keeps parsing my spaces out when i comments, there is like 4 spaces between P: and the start of \\UNC_Path

Comment: ok, if you specify TOKENS=1 then it parses the space for me, thanks.